# Is it a crime to sneak into a hotel pool?

Tags: florida, trespass

Suppose a hotel pool is very easy to get into, although there is a sign that it is only for the hotel guests. Is getting caught punishable by law enforcement? This is in Orange County, Florida, USA.

Comment: Depending on the level of anger of the establishment, you may be told to leave, but you also may get trespassed.

Answer (score 5):

- Short Answer:

If there are signs prohibiting non-guests then it's more than likely to be misdemeanor in the first degree.

- Long Answer:

The offence is one of trespass contrary to Florida's [TITLE XLVI, Chapter 810.09](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0800-0899/0810/Sections/0810.09.html):

> (1)(a) A person who, without being authorized, licensed, or invited, willfully enters upon or remains in any property other than a structure or conveyance:
>
> 1. As to which notice against entering or remaining is given, either by actual communication to the offender or by posting, fencing, or cultivation as described in s. [810.011](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0800-0899/0810/Sections/0810.011.html); or
>
> 2. [omitted]
>
> commits the offense of trespass on property other than a structure or conveyance.
>
> ;(b) [omitted]
>
> (2)(a) Except as provided in this subsection, **trespass on property other than a structure or conveyance is a misdemeanor of the first degree**, punishable as provided in [s. 775.082](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0700-0799/0775/Sections/0775.082.html)<sup>1</sup> or [s. 775.083](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0700-0799/0775/Sections/0775.083.html)<sup>2</sup>.

The general power of arrest, at [901.15](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0900-0999/0901/Sections/0901.15.html#:%7E:text=The%202021%20Florida%20Statutes&text=901.15%20When%20arrest%20by%20officer,the%20presence%20of%20the%20officer.), requires a warrant for this offence unless certain conditions are met, as explained [here](https://criminaldefenseattorneytampa.com/warrant-for-arrest/warrantless-arrest/):

> When can an officer in Florida make a warrantless arrest for a misdemeanor? As a general rule, a warrant is required for a misdemeanor arrest unless:
>
> - all of the elements of the misdemeanor were committed in the officer’s presence; or
> - the officer has probable cause for the arrest and the misdemeanor is on the list of statutory exceptions found in Section 901.15, F.S.; or
> - the officer has reasonable grounds to believe that the subject has violated probation or community control in any material respect (sometimes called the “COP VOP” exception contained in Section 948.06).

<sup>1</sup> The more likely punishments, based on a lack of specific detail, seem to be:

> For a misdemeanor of the first degree, by a definite term of imprisonment not exceeding 1 year

<sup>2</sup>Or:

> [not exceeding] $1,000, when the conviction is of a misdemeanor of the first degree

Note that these punishments are *maximums* the court could impose if the hotel wanted to pursue the matter criminally.

Comment: Note also that even if there aren't any signs prohibiting trespassing, you have to leave if asked; that's what the "actual communication" phrase means in the text of the law.